# SQL form run from include not working in firefox/safari

Tags: php, forms, firefox, safari

**
This is the code for one of several forms saved as php includes for use on the same admin page. They work individually in all browsers but do not work in safari or firefox from the admin page. Any Thoughts?
Thanks for your help!
(I know I need to switch over to prepared statements) **

```
<?php
$servername = "1.1.1.1:111";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "sit";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `calltoaction` ");
$values = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$calltoaction_title = $_POST['calltoaction_title'];
$calltoaction_content = $_POST['calltoaction_content'];

if(isset($_POST['calltoaction_title'])){

$calltoaction= "UPDATE calltoaction SET calltoaction_title='$calltoaction_title' ,calltoaction_content='$calltoaction_content' WHERE  calltoaction_id='1'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $calltoaction)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}   


}

?>

<form id="comment_form" method="post" action="<?php $calltoaction?>" onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10), location.reload(true);">
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">



<tr>
<td width="85%">About Us Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="commentarea" name="calltoaction_title" type="text" id="calltoaction_title"value="<?php echo $values['calltoaction_title']?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="85%" >Testimonial</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="85%" >About Us Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><pre><textarea class="commentarea" name="calltoaction_content" type="text" id="calltoaction_content" rows= "10" ><?php echo $values['calltoaction_content']?></textarea></pre></td>
</tr>


<tr>  
<td>

<input type="submit" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
 </table>
</form>

<?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```